# show and hide toggle js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code in a page

```
<div class="filterGroup">
                  <ul>              
                    <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
                    <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
                    <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
                    <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and this to toggle it

```
   $('.moreFiltersLink').click(function () {
        $('.moreFilters').toggle();         
    });
```

the problem i have is i want to your say 5 blocks of the 
`<div class="filterGroup">`

which means when i click the link all the blocks toggle.

Can anyone help me change this to only toggle classes within the div you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the closest .moreFiltersLink, find it's .moreFilters, and toggle them:

```
$('.moreFiltersLink').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.filterGroup').find('.moreFilters').toggle();         
});
```

Comment: Thanks this looks a very neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery selectors, you can toggle them with:

```
$('.filterGroup .moreFilters').toggle();
```

That selector will select all elements with class moreFilters that are within an element with class filterGroup.

I think the best and most reliable way would be to assign an id to each of the  and toggle them with:

```
$('#filterGroupId .moreFilters').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `siblings` to select it's nearest element

```js
$(function(){
  $('.moreFiltersLink').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.moreFilters').toggle();         
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filterGroup">
 <ul>              
  <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="filterGroup">
 <ul>              
  <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="filterGroup">
 <ul>              
  <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="filterGroup">
 <ul>              
  <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="filterGroup">
 <ul>              
  <li><label class="checkbox">Argentina<input type="checkbox"></label></li>                       
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Spain<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFilters"><label class="checkbox">Turkey<input type="checkbox"></label></li> 
  <li class="moreFiltersLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```